# how to hide page info from confirmation popup (phonegap, jquery, iPhone)

Tags: jquery, iphone, objective-c, cordova

I am using same code for Windows phone, Android and iPhone.
There is no problem with WP and Android but when Confirmation popup appears on iPhone device I can see current page as a header of the popup. How can I remove or change this?
Here is the code for my confirmation:

```
var conf= confirm("choose yes or no");
if(conf == true) ...
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What framework are you using to create the confirm? I am asking because that is not standard javascript to build the confirm window. Are you using the notification plugin? JQM? Need more code of what is actually building it please.

Comment: well - it is classic JavaScript confirmation method. It is just a confirmation. YES/NO/. When I run it the current page is displayed, which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the notification API instead of the core javascript confirm. Documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification).

Comment: Please stop robo-reviewing.